# MAMP + dreamweaver + delay issue

Tags: php

I am very very new at PHP programming.

I am making up some code to test my learning but I just discovered a very annoying problem.

I have no idea about the cause, so following I'll describe my situation and I'll leave to you the "honor" to find the problem :)

I use dreamweaver to write my PHP code.

Once I made all the changes, I save the file and refresh the browser page to see the result.
Well, here is the problem. For like 30seconds nothing changes, after this time delay the page actually refreshes. There seems to be a delay between when I save the modified file in dreamweaver and when the browser (Chrome in my case) sees the new file.

I tried different browsers and I also verified that the file is physically changed...I have no clue.

Comment: where is your code? how can we know without codes? (*sidenote:* Dreamweaver is not a very good PHP editor, in my personal opinion. Too complex for simple scripting.)

Comment: Could it be that your script is taking too long to execute?

Comment: Are you saving your files to a remote drive (not part of your local computer)? It could be either network latency or something on the computer that you are saving the files to.

Comment: Have you tried just writing a file in a plain text editor and saving it to a new local environment? I doubt dreamweaver has anything to do with this considering it is still just writing a file to system despite being a wild POS. Never the less, worth seeing if it really is part of the equation.

Comment: @ shivan: my code is the classic "hello world"...so I believe the code is not a problem here.
@ Shomz: as before, the code runs fast since it is like a "hello world" :)
@ Jon: I'm saving everything in local and using MAMP as server
@ Kai: just tried...I modified the file with a text editor and same problem. I do not get the new page until the abovementioned 30seconds or so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with Dreamweaver.

**You have to disable OPCache**

Some software such as MAMP turns on OPCache by default in the php configuration file (php.ini), you can disable it this way

```
opcache.revalidate_freq=0
```